# Code completion and syntax checking, in a browser

Tags: javascript, html

I need to implement a functionality very similar to [IntelliSense in Visual Studio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intellisense#IntelliSense):

- code completion
- syntax checking

But in a web page.

Is there any framework out there to achieve so? What would be the best approach for it?

Comment: You've tagged this JS so I'm **guessing** you want a JS library for this - however for clarity.... are you also interested in Flash/Silverlight/other plugin based methods? What browser(s) do you need at minimum? Do you care about pricing?

Comment: I'm not interested in any other plugin based methods, and I just need the current browsers, FF, Chrome, and IE. Pricing can be looked at

Comment: What languages does it need to support?

Comment: I would like to add my own reserved instructions as we have a proprietary language

Comment: My recommendation should be pretty easy to add your own hinting/syntax highlighting to

Comment: I see there's a demo but you need to press ctrl+space to activate it, uhhm not really intuitive

Comment: It is quite customizable with options in initialization. All the code is exposed so is fairly easy to do drastic editing for further customization. There are **lots** of [demos](http://codemirror.net/demo/) available.

Comment: Yeah that is a bit silly - I haven't needed that feature so I'm not sure *how* easy it is to enable autocomplete under more sensible conditions (like hmm input of 3 characters other than space)

Comment: Thanks anyway, this is the kind of framework I was looking for, I'll definitely give it a go

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well I've been using [CodeMirror](http://codemirror.net/) in a [TinyMCE](http://tinymce.com/) plugin that I've done a couple edits to; and I *just* now realized that you can enable [code hinting](http://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#addon_show-hint) as well as syntax highlighting which I knew. Currently hinting support is available for JS, XML, HTML, Python, SQL, CSS/LESS/SCSS and "any word". It should be quite easy to add hinting support for other languages given those example files and a good understanding of the other language.

CodeMirror is [open-source](https://github.com/marijnh/CodeMirror/) under the MIT License and free. Optionally you can also purchase a commercial support license.